# Silverlight 4 - Persist user settings to isolated storage

Tags: silverlight, settings, isolatedstorage

The full .NET platform has a great feature for storing user options in Settings files, which conveniently support saving and loading.  Has anyone created an analog to this for Silverlight?  I'd like the settings to be stored client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight has an IsolatedStorage API as well - you can save/retrieve discrete elements via a dictionary as well as a full file system API in Isolated Storage.

1. Create a class that can be serialized via XML (use the DataContractSerializer)
2. Serialize object on close/Deserialize the object on open.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the IsolatedStorageSettings. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.95).aspx)